# JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final - Accessing EJBs deployed in JBoss AS 6

Tags: jboss, ejb, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

I need to access EJBs deployed in JBoss AS 6, but I am using JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final, which dropped the JNP lookup.

Is it possible to do so, or do I need to downgrade to JBoss AS 6 (upgrading the other server is impossible)?

I've dug through the AS 7 forums and SO, but did not find any references for this..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general EJB remote communication between two different servers never works.

JBoss is especially known to have a total lack of attention for compatibility. Even a minor difference in version (a minor security update for instance) is already enough to break compatibility. I know for a fact that EJB remoting between JBoss AS 5 and 6 does not work, and I'm pretty sure it doesn't work between 6 and 7.

The root of the problem is that Java EE never specified how remote bean discovery should take place and what the requirements for the client exactly are (one exception is the application client container, which only works in Java SE and is so arcane that almost nobody uses it).

Most vendors use some kind of client jar, which in case of Jboss is nearly the entire server. Because it's nearly the entire server, you can't include it in another server as hundreds if not thousands of classes would clash.

A Jboss employee once started an experiment with an isolating class loader that would load these clients libs isolated from the main server, but as far as I know nobody ever got this to work.

Comment: I eventually came to that conclusion and resigned for downgrading to JBoss AS 6..

At least it works now :D

Accepted your answer as it might be of interest to whoever has this problem (though I find odd the lack of references to this..).

Thanks!

Comment: At least for some time Jboss had a matrix on their site, showing which versions were compatible (spoiler not a lot were). I guess the Java EE community is a bit ashamed of this situation and thus doesn't brag about it. Last news is that "they" quietly want to drop remoting completely.